# SciSpark: Reading from local folder instead of HDFS folder

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hdfs

I use an enterprise cluster that has both local and HDFS filesystems. Files I need to process are in netcdf format and hence I use [SciSpark](https://scispark.jpl.nasa.gov/) to load. On a workstation that has no HDFS, the code reads from local folder. However, when HDFS folders are present, it attempts read from HDFS only. As the size of files present in the folder is huge (running cumulatively into hundreds of GBs to TBs), I am having to copy them to HDFS, which is inefficient and inconvenient. The (Scala) code I use for loading the files is shown below:

```
val ncFilesRDD = sc.netcdfDFSFiles(ncDirectoryPath, List("x1", "x2", "x3"))
val ncFileCRDArrayRDD = ncFilesRDD.map(x => (x.variables.get("x1").get.data.toArray,
                             x.variables.get("x2").get.data.toArray,
                             x.variables.get("x3").get.data.toArray
                             ))
```

I would very much appreciate any help in modifying the code that will enable me to use local directory instead of HDFS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Source Code Comment Doc for `netcdfDFSFiles` says
`that since the files are read from HDFS`

Not sure if you can use `netcdfDFSFiles` to read from local.

But there is another function `netcdfFileList` which says : `The URI could be an OpenDapURL or a filesystem path.`

Since it can take `filesystem path` , you can use it like

```
val ncFilesRDD = sc.netcdfFileList("file://your/path", List("x1", "x2", "x3"))
```

The `file://` will look for local dir only.

Comment: Thank you for the response. The code works if HDFS is not available and I have been using it for benchmarking on other systems. Will try your suggestion and let you know of the result.

Comment: Did you try using `file://` in your path for the function  `netcdfDFSFiles`.

Comment: Just did. `val ncFilesRDD = sc.netcdfFileList("file:///bigdata/home/IPDATA", List("x1", "x2", "x3"))`. Some RDD was created with correct number of files, but next step failed. `java.io.FileNotFoundException: CDF`. I am trying to see if giving list of files with full path would be helpful.

Comment: It worked, finally! I had to give a filelist (ie, files with with complete path) and place it as a single file in a directory. Then it picked the filelist, and loaded files. It should work similarly with multiple file lists as well. Thanks a lot!

Comment: that's Awesome ! :)